# How to check the return of this callback

Tags: javascript, callback, titanium

I'm a total newb if it comes to callbacks, so i've tried some googling. But the code(Someone gave me on a forum) is very different than the callback examples i came across.

Can anyone please elaborate on how i get the check this result for true or false?

```
exports.testGPS = function(_callback) {
    Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Recieve User Location";
    Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
    if (_callback && typeof(_callback)==='function') {
        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            _callback ((e.error) ? false: true);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Here's my call:

```
functions.testGPS(function () {
    //If true/false
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an argument for your function:

```
functions.testGPS(function (thereWasAnError) {
    if (thereWasAnError) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback returned as a parameter the result of the function. Add the returned variable and check it

```
functions.testGPS(function (result) {
    if(result)
    {
       //TRUE
    }
    else
    {
       //FALSE
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function say FetchResult()

```
function fetchResult(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
```

Call the function passing the callback,

```
exports.testGPS(fetchResult)
```

Automatically, the result will be passed to your function with call to fetchResult.